# Reviewer workflow is confusing to OP approving suggested edits to their post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, wording

When an OP approves a suggested edit, the following message is displayed:

[image: Thank you for your review. You need at least 2k reputation to continue reviewing suggested edits.]

The message *"...continue reviewing suggested edits"* is confusing because it pertains to a reviewer, someone with Review privileges, who is consciously going through a review queue voting on suggestions.

But the OP may not be doing that, may not have Review privileges, may not even know what that means.  The OP is just responding to a notification about a suggested edit to their own post. There is nothing for the OP to "continue". Worse, it is not clear from this message that the OP's approval is [binding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work?rq=1). The suggested edit is immediately applied to the post. This is, essentially, "success" but the message looks nothing like success.

**Suggestion:** The Reviewer workflow should not be applied to OP approval on their own posts. Instead, the message should just be "Thank you, the suggested edit has been applied.".

Similarly, but less critical, if an OP goes back to the suggested edit, the following message is shown:

[image: Dialog: "You have already voted on this suggested edit to your post and no further action is required." Review below: "Approved 53 secs ago: jay613 reviewed this 53 secs ago: Approve"]

It's not as critical IMO but a better message would be "The suggested edit has been applied and no further action is required".

**Both** of these confusing messages are particularly confusing to low-rep OPs who may not even know that "review queues" exist, but even experienced users may not understand what's going on when they are in the workflow of approving a good edit to their own post after seeing such notified.

Comment: How is it confusing that you lack the reputation to continue?

Comment: To continue what?  As post author my approval of the edit is [binding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work?rq=1).  The edit is immediately applied.    So what is it that I cannot continue?

Comment: @Luuklag Seems confusing to me. I'm not even sure what the workflow is like for a low-rep user who gets an edit suggestion... it really shouldn't be treated as a "review" in that sense.

Comment: @Catija changing it so that OP will get something totally different is complex, don't think it's worth the efforts; People who wonder about it and want to learn come here, and get an answer.

Comment: Perhaps my suggestion should be "OP review approval should follow different workflow from Reviewer approval".  I just didn't have the knowledge to ask that until reading these comments and answer.

Comment: A message telling you that you cannot continue doing something that you were not doing to begin with, do not have the privileges to access, and probably are completely unaware of ... is a bad message.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 It's already different text! It's not super complex to make it more transparent for someone who has likely never used review before and won't have been shown the guidance for how review works.

Comment: I am going to edit the question in light of my better understanding of the problem, formed from these comments and the ones below.   Some of the above comments may become redundant or hard to understand as a result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue! I just deployed an update.

The message displayed when the author of a post approves a suggested edit has been changed to:

> Thanks for reviewing the suggested edit - the changes (if any) are now live. [Click here] to return to the post.

Also, the message displayed when the author of a post returns to the review page for a suggested edit that they approved has been changed to:

> You voted on this suggested edit to your post as noted below. No further action is required.

The "Next Task" button is also removed for users who don't have enough reputation to continue reviewing.

Comment: Jeez, I haven't had a suggested edit in weeks, but I received one three hours ago and I said to myself "ohhhhhhh that message again".  Talk about unlucky timing!  Now I look forward to someone pointing out my next error.   *Is this implemented across all sites?*

Comment: @jay613 Yes it's implemented across all sites.

Comment: Thank you developers.   Here's something funny: This post author made a minor edit to my above post so that I could experience the new functionality.   But two moderators rejected his edit before I even had a chance to see it.   :-O   Don't worry, I'll see it eventually somewhere else.

Answer (score -9):

Sorry but I don't find it unclear at all, and don't think the suggested changes will improve it.

The reasoning behind the first message is that normally, after reviewing an item, the user gets another item to review, that's how review works on Stack Exchange. However, since you don't have enough reputation, you can't review other items.

As for the second message, normally it takes (at least) two users to  approve or reject a suggested edit. So when someone enters this page with normal review "power" and there is only one reviewer before, they'll be able to perform an action: approve or reject the suggested edit.

Comment: So it's not confusing from the perspective of someone with Review privileges who is in the workflow of approving various suggested edits.   But from the perspective of a post author who may be completely naive about this entire topic, does not know what review queues are or that they exist, but was just notified of a suggestion about their own post, that message is worse than confusing, it is entirely meaningless.

Comment: @jay613 well, review is a "tool" used by Stack Exchange users. Normally it's given only to users with high reputation, so they should know about it, having it available for any user, even totally new, on their own posts is kind of "bonus", but it's still using the same exact tool as high rep user.

Comment: I get it.  And it is confusing.  I'm not saying that the implementation of a solution is trivial, or even that it should be a priority.   But as with any software, low priority and high cost is not a reason to reject the *existence* of a problem.  You just put it on the back burner.

Comment: Look ... I *do* have Review privileges on other forums, but not the one where I experienced this message, and I have used those privileges many times, and *despite that*, in the workflow I was in, I was unable to make the connection and to understand that message.    I'm no genius, but I don't think my level of stupidity and unawareness is orders of magnitude worse than most people.  It's confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful it is for a user who has been around for more than a decade and has over 200K rep across the network to insist that a bunch of irrelevant info about a review queue an author can't access is perfectly clear when given in the context of them applying a suggested edit to their post. I think you underestimate the effect of your "[tribal knowledge](https://everipedia.org/wiki/lang_en/Tribal_knowledge)" of how SE works in your assessment of how not-confusing things are to less experienced users.